# How do I properly import Billiard in a python script in order to use Queue?

Tags: python, python-billiard

I know this questions sounds stupid but i'm not finding a solution.

In Billiard's docs all the imports look like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
```

When I do the import like that, I'm not using billiard but the python in-built multiprocessing package, which doesn't work for me since I'm working with Celery.

if I do the import like this:

```
from billiard.context import Process
from billiard.queues import Queue
```

the I receive the following error when I instantiate a Queue:

```
TypeError: missing 1 required keyword-only argument: ctx
```

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Sad to see that nobody has had any thoughts on this, I have the same question...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from billiard import Process, Queue
```

Comment: Have you tested this with python 2.7 ?